# How to create a toggle button in gravity forms which freezes once change from Open to close in wordpress?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, wordpress

I'have created a form using gravity forms plugin in WordPress in which I want to have a toggle button like this below:

[image]

When the button is set to close it should never get set open. Can any one help me out with this I ' m new to wordpress I dont know how to do it using wordpress and I have an addon of gravity form that is gravity view that must show the output in that view that it is open or closed.
Thank You !

Comment: Do you have any code associated with it?

Comment: I have tried in Java script basic if ..else condition  but on page refresh it get back to open and I don't want it to change ..... :( @PalSingh

Comment: How the button will be set to "Close" state? on server side or if it is set to closed on client side, it should not "Open" again?

Comment: Ya Exactly It should not Open again can you help me out with it that how can I do It ?  @PalSingh

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the button with the following code:

```
const btn = document.getElementById('test'); // use your button/input id here
btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    if (!btn.disabled) {
        btn.disabled = true;
    }
});
```